# Twitter API created_at field value "acts funny"

Tags: python, api, twitter

When getting date values from twitter API, key "created_at", the format looks like:
`Wed Apr 01 22:09:52 +0000 2020` given in what I believe to be UTC.

My question is focused on time inconsistency. Data is fetched using `api.GetUserTimeline(screen_name=screen_name, count=count)`.

When comparing the API to twitter.com/realdonaldtrump/status/id there are significant timestamp differences. Please see my [Google Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vQgCkzbpEZCxN-otUPq21TczSElbBBA908RSOIYHpTzzPyPPtNRoypbzq_1sWF-jNmRQONfzAPJ579I/pubhtml?gid=979455398&single=true)

This inconsistency distorts my time-series database.

example: https://twitter.com/realDonaldTrump/status/1245006056583036929

```
#oAuth passes keys omitted from post

# Variables
count = 1
screen_name = 'whitehouse'

# print user tweets
t = api.GetUserTimeline(screen_name=screen_name, count=count)

# Convert to dictionary list
tweets = [i.AsDict() for i in t]

# Loop t and print records
for t in tweets:
    print(t['id'], t['created_at'])
```

Direction into what may be occurring would be appreciated.

Thank You for the help